# Apex Email Validation

Tags: apex, email, regular-expressions, email-validation

> String email ='shilpa..test@gmail.com'
>
> Boolean isValid =
>   Pattern.matches('([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,}|[0-9]{1,3})',email);

I am trying to validate the email in apex, but before @ the above expression is allowing double dot (..), can anyone help me to modify this regex?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you take a look at Salesforce's [documentation on allowed email address formats](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000001145&language=en_US&type=1) then search for pre-defined regex that validates against RFC 2822. It may be that Salesforce further constrains the specification so you may need to tweak the expression. (Try googling "rfc 2822 regex".)

In the short term, you could simply split the "local" part of your match (i.e. before the "@") to be something more like:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```

Comment: Note that this local part is far more restrictive than Salesforce allows. It rather depends on just what you want to achieve.

Comment: The above solution work for not allowing dot which are together like shilpa..abc@gamil.com but doesn't work for seperate dot in email like shilpa.abc.test@gmail.com.

Comment: @Shilpa You need a [very complicated regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323) if you want to properly validate email addresses. They're far more complicated than you think.

Comment: I don't want very complex & proper email validation. from above regex (given n problem) after @ every thing works fine, but before @ i am facing some problems. Before @ email should allow abc.djhd.hfjdj and test--test--test--test-test.test.test_test__test but should not allow double dot continuously like test..test

Comment: @Shilpa, I changed the regex for the local part to allow a.b.c.d etc. by simply indicating that the ".x" part can be repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: You should note that Salesforce allows ".." in email addresses.